# How to pull dashDB docker image

Tags: docker, dashdb

I currently try to install a dashDB Local (called now Db2 Warehouse) to a linux machine :

```
[root@lat131 ~]# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.3 (Maipo)"
```

Before trying to use docker, I have subscribed to the dashDB Local trial, and received an email to confirm all is okay.

According to the IBM online documentation (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/admin/linux_deploy.html), I have tried following things:

```
[root@lat131 ~]# systemctl stop firewalld
[root@lat131 ~]# docker login -u=MYUSER -p='MYPASS'
Login Succeeded
[root@lat131 ~]# docker pull ibmdashdb/local:latest-linux
Trying to pull repository registry.access.redhat.com/ibmdashdb/local ... 
Trying to pull repository docker.io/ibmdashdb/local ... 
Pulling repository docker.io/ibmdashdb/local
Error: image ibmdashdb/local:latest-linux not found
```

Any ideas how I can pull such an image?

Maybe there is a difference between online documentation (old name) and the real image name on servers (new name)?

Thanks

Stephane

Comment: Someone would have an idea? I'm always stuck with this issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instructions for downloading and deploying Db2 Warehouse and the product images are on a private repository page, which you can access only after you complete a registration process.

source on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/dashdb/local/)

To register for Db2 Warehouse, you'll first need an IBM account:

Go to the [signup page](https://www.ibm.com/account/us-en/signup/register.html?a=NDllOGRkMjMtMTI0My00&ctx=C001&cc=us&lc=en&source=mrsaas-trial-ibmid&pk&S_TACT=M1610S4W)

Create an account. You'll also need an account on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/).
After signing up you can start the dashDB free trial.

You will receive an email confirmation within 24 hours from the Docker system with the link to the IBM® dashDB Local container download.

You can use that link to download your image.

Comment: Thanks but as I said earlier "I have subscribed to the dashDB Local trial, and received an email to confirm all is okay", so I have already done all the things you have mentioned (ibm account, email confirmation within 24h etc.). I have an old image on another system, I'll work with this old one by exporting/importing the image.

Comment: @Steph You didn't receive an email of IBM after 24h's? Maybe contact their support? I just tried the same with all new accounts so I can tell you tomorrow if it works for me.

Comment: I have already received the confirmation email from IBM, but unfortunately the pull of latest linux image doesn't work for me